# Convert characters with time units (ms, s, us) into numerics

Tags: r, time, type-conversion

One of the columns in my data frame is a character vector with time span values represented as number+suffix, as so:

```
c("16.14ms", "7.58ms", "8.38ms", "7.29ms", "6.40ms", "5.76ms", 
"5.56ms", "5.27us", "5.12ms", "5.03us", "4.91ms", "4.76ms", "16.12ms", 
"7.56ms", "8.59ms", "7.16ms", "6.59ms", "5.91s", "5.62ms", "5.44ms"
)
```

The units are limited to micro `us`, milli `ms`, and full seconds `s`.

Is there a simple way to make this into a numeric column with all values being either in milliseconds or seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some approaches.  We suppose `x` is the input vector shown in the question.

**1)** Remove the `s`, replace `m` with `e-3` and replace `u` with `e-6`.  Then convert to numeric:

```
as.numeric(sub("u", "e-6", sub("m", "e-3", sub("s", "", x))))
```

**2)** This could also be done neatly using gsubfn.  First we match the suffix and then use a replacement list as shown:

```
library(gsubfn)

as.numeric(gsubfn("\\D+$", list(ms = "e-3", us = "e-6", s = "e0"), x))
```

This would be particularly convenient if it were desired to extend the problem to many time units as it would just be a matter of extending the list.

Note that at the top of page 4 of the gsubfn vignette there is an example which is very close to this one.

Comment: That works perfectly, and the approach totally escaped me. I was looking for functions to format character vectors as time, thanks for the pointer!