# R: Formatting youtube video duration into proper time (seconds)

Tags: r, string-formatting

I have vector (column data) which contains youtube playback duration in a character string format in R.

```
x <- c(PT1H8S, PT9M55S, PT13M57S, PT1M5S, PT30M12S, PT1H21M5S, PT6M48S, PT31S, PT2M)
```

How do I get rid of `PT` then get the overall duration in seconds format?

Resultant vector should be `c(3608, 595, 837, 65, 1812, 4865, 408, 31, 120)`

example: `PT1H21M5S` in the form of seconds = 4865.
(calculated as `1H = 1*3600`, `21M = 21*60`, `5S = 5*1`)

Comment: I think this should get you going: [Dealing with durations defined by days, hours, minutes and seconds such as “1d 3h 2m 28s” in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802903/dealing-with-durations-defined-by-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds-such-as-1d-3); [Convert characters with time units (ms, s, us) into numerics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617467/convert-characters-with-time-units-ms-s-us-into-numerics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little apply loop with regex commands, deleting everything but the seconds, minutes, or hours and then converting everything into seconds.

```
x <- c("PT1H8S", "PT9M55S", "PT13M57S", "PT1M5S", "PT30M12S", "PT1H21M5S", "PT6M48S")
x2 <- sapply(x, function(i){
  t <- as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)M|^(.*)H|S$", "", i))
  if(grepl("M", i)) t <- t + as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)PT|^(.*)H|M(.*)$", "",i)) * 60
  if(grepl("H", i)) t <- t + as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)PT|H(.*)$", "",i)) * 3600
  t
})
x2
   PT1H8S   PT9M55S  PT13M57S    PT1M5S  PT30M12S PT1H21M5S   PT6M48S 
 3608       595       837        65      1812      4865       408
```

EDIT: Per request

```
x <- c("PT1H8S", "PT9M55S", "PT13M57S", "PT1M5S", "PT30M12S", "PT1H21M5S", "PT6M48S", "PT31S", "PT2M")
x2 <- sapply(x, function(i){
  t <- 0
  if(grepl("S", i)) t <- t + as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)PT|^(.*)M|^(.*)H|S$", "", i))
  if(grepl("M", i)) t <- t + as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)PT|^(.*)H|M(.*)$", "",i)) * 60
  if(grepl("H", i)) t <- t + as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)PT|H(.*)$", "",i)) * 3600
  t
})
x2
   PT1H8S   PT9M55S  PT13M57S    PT1M5S  PT30M12S PT1H21M5S   PT6M48S     PT31S      PT2M 
     3608       595       837        65      1812      4865       408        31       120
```

This should cover all the cases. If there are more, the trick is to alter the regex. `^` is the beginning of the character vector, `$` is the end. `(.*)` is everything. So `^(.*)H` means everything between beginning and H. We replace this with nothing.

Comment: @JobGrub Thanks. One more thing, can you modify your code little bit when I pass `PT31S` or `PT2M`, it's giving me the error, I have also added `PT31S` to my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` and `stringr` solution:

```
df %>%
  # extract hours, minutes, and seconds and convert to numeric:
  mutate(
    h = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=PT)\\d+(?=H)")),
    m = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=PT|H)\\d+(?=M)")),
    s = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=PT|H|M)\\d+(?=S)"))
  ) %>%
  # replace NA with 0:
  mutate(
    across(everything(), replace_na, 0)
  ) %>%
  # calculate time in seconds:
  mutate(sec = h*3600+m*60+s)
          x h  m  s  sec
1    PT1H8S 1  0  8 3608
2   PT9M55S 0  9 55  595
3  PT13M57S 0 13 57  837
4    PT1M5S 0  1  5   65
5  PT30M12S 0 30 12 1812
6 PT1H21M5S 1 21  5 4865
7   PT6M48S 0  6 48  408
8     PT31S 0  0 31   31
9      PT2M 0  2  0  120
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("PT1H8S", "PT9M55S", "PT13M57S", "PT1M5S", "PT30M12S", "PT1H21M5S", "PT6M48S", "PT31S", "PT2M"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
 
 x <- c("PT1H8S", "PT9M55S", "PT13M57S", "PT1M5S", "PT30M12S", "PT1H21M5S", "PT6M48S")
 
 x2 <- as.numeric(duration(x))
 
 x2
[1] 3608  595  837   65 1812 4865  408
```